# UIImagePickerController as Main View Controller of Application and Navigation Controller shown afterwards

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

My goal is to create an application which features the camera as the first view that appears and then after taking a picture goes to a series of views which are in a navigation controller.  The closest existing application to what I want to make is Snapchat.

I've been struggling with this for several days, here's what I have tried (none of these seem to work).

1. Root View (Inside Navigation Controller) Presents a Modal UIImagePickerController and then segues to next view. [Does not segue]
2. Same as 1, but dismiss the modal controller then segue. [Kinda Works. Shows the background when loading the UIImagePicker and also when transitioning to the next view]
3. Use a subclass of UIIMagePickerController as the root view.[Works but does not allow navigation bar to be shown or else crashes on displaying the UIImagePickerController][
4. Use 3 and don't embed inside a navigation controller (reasoning: since UIImagePickerController is a subclass of navigation controller this should work). [Does not work.]

I've tried about 10 other ways to do the same thing and they fall in this category: [Kinda Works. Most crash or look look ugly].

What is the best way to do this?  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Again if this is confusing, just open snapchat and play with the flow (same flow, totally different idea for the actual app - ie. not a snapchat clone :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you present the image picker modally from the navigation controller's root view controller with no animation, then the picker is what you will see first. When you dismiss it, you'll see that root controller, which should be what ever you want to see first when the picker goes away. Is that what you want? This code would be in the root controller:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    static int first = 1;
    if (first) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = 0;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
        first = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I actually do this right now, but I see the background view controller before the modal pops up.  Additionally after dismissing the modal and before segueing to the next pushed view, I see the background view controller again.  (I guess I could make the background view controller the next one that is going to be pushed but that still doesn't solve the first problem.)

Comment: @NV, I don't know why you see that -- I don't. You have animated set to NO? I don't even see a flicker of the root controller's view.

Answer (score 0):

1st Suggestion:

Make one mainController and add the buttons(depends on how many viewController you have), when button clicked each button will load different viewController.

```
// appDelegate.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *mainController;

//appDelegate.m

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

self.mainController = [[[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;


//each button clicked has following IBAction:

-(IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender

{

        FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC]autorelease];
        [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
        [addVC release];
}

//in FirstViewController.m

-(void)viewDidLoad 

{

        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.title = @"xxxx ";

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                            target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)]autorelease];

}

-(void) cancel_Clicked:(id)sender {

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note :

ViewController to be embedded inside a navigation controller, the following code has to be used;

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC]autorelease];
```